# how to distribute the work of an activity between specific number of individuals of a kind from a work resource

Tags: ms-project, scheduling

I have added a work resource entry "Laborers" with Max. Units 10000% in the Resource Sheet. The resource calendar for this resource is standard and all the units are available.

Now I want the work of Activity A (350h during 30 working days) is distributed equally between three general laborers from resource "Laborers". Show me the way resource definition and assignment should be for this purpose using Microsoft Project 2013.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

- In "Task Sheet", select the activity, and enter "Laborers [300%]" in cell for "Resource Names". As my schedule is effort-driven, MSP keep the activity work unchanged but reduces the activity duration. In "Task Usage", you can see three laborers working the total of 24h every working day during the activity duration. In the next step, I fix the work distribution to be done over the planned activity duration.
- In activity duration field, enter 30d. After that, an action button is displayed next to the field. From that, choose "Decrease the hours resources work per day (units) but keep the same amount of work". Check "Task Usage" and you should see 3.89h as daily work for "Laborers".

SWEET